# I want to make a variable of several repeating string values in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I want to make a data frame that has a single variable with 345 entries as follows:
entries 1:149 to be "2020",
entries 150:297 to be "2021" and
entries 298:345 to be "2022".

I am entirely not sure how to put this together. I feel like it is a simple problem but I have been at this for an hour with no progress. I would extremely appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rep` to repeat a string for a desired number of time.

```
data.frame(year = c(rep("2020", 149), 
                    rep("2021", 297 - 150 + 1), 
                    rep("2022", 345 - 298 + 1)))
```

Or set a dataframe with an empty column named `year`, and set row values accordingly.

```
df <- data.frame(year = "")

df[1:149,] <- "2020"
df[150:297, ] <- "2021"
df[298:345,] <- "2022"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `times` argument in `rep` to make this a bit easier:

```r
df <- data.frame(year = as.character(rep(2020:2022, times = c(149, 148, 48))))
```